# CDATA xml parsing

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am getting response in xml format and data are inside cData section in xml nodes. now when i am trying to extract node value then getting value with cdata text.

how can i parse it?

xml:

```
<myrecords>
<record>
<id><![CDATA[8683]]></id>
<tempid><![CDATA[4567]]></id>
<type><![CDATA[db]]></type>   
<params>  
<![CDATA[<db>   <dbid>254</dbid>     <isdb>true</isdb>   <mydb>sample</mydb>    </db>]]>
</params>  
</record>
</myrecords>
```

i used code to get entire list but i need to get only particular node

```
 foreach (var child in xdoc.Root.Elements())
            {                   
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}",child.Name,child.Value);
                    }
```

the above code list all the cdata value..

i need to get only dbid,isdb,mydb values from the above xml

Answer (score 0):

For the "outer" Xml document, the value is nothing but character data. You'll have to parse that value separately if you want to treat it as Xml.

Comment: i am unable to retrive value sepeartely